# Finding common elements within a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following code

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

}

public List<int> GetCustomerIds()
{
    var orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>
    {
        new OrderDetails {OrderId = 1001, CustomerId = 2001},
        new OrderDetails {OrderId = 1001, CustomerId = 2002},

        new OrderDetails {OrderId = 1002, CustomerId = 2003},
        new OrderDetails {OrderId = 1002, CustomerId = 2002},

        new OrderDetails {OrderId = 1003, CustomerId = 2003},
        new OrderDetails {OrderId = 1003, CustomerId = 2002},     
        //return list of common customerIds.           
    };
}
```

I want to get a list of `CustomerIds` that are common across all orders. In the example above my output would be `2002`. What is a clean way of achieving this?

Comment: @GrantWinney It is common across all OrderIds.

Comment: Took me a moment as well before I figured it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will accomplish what you want:

```
var result = orders.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
                   .Where(y => y.Count() == orderDetails.GroupBy(z => z.OrderId)
                                                        .Count())
                   .FirstOrDefault()
                   .Key;
```

Output:

> 2002

We can read the purpose from the query in English:

- Group your collection on the `CustomerId`
- Gather how many different orders there are by grouping on `OrderId` and getting the `Count()`
- Filter the collection to those customers which appear as often as there are orders
- Select the first
- Print the key (which is the `CustomerId`)

Important note: this will only take the first customer in case there are multiple with the same amount of orders, but changing this to take them all is trivial.

Comment: Thank you. I get the desired result. But was looking for a more concise and clear way of doing it. Reading the code it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. And it only returns the first customer. Just a thought...

Answer (score 1):

First find the total number of orders, then group the order details by customer and finally select the customers with the same number of orders as the total number of orders. This assumes no duplicate customer order pairs.

```
var numberOrders = orderDetails.Select(orderDetail => orderDetail.OrderId)
                               .Distinct()
                               .Count();

var result = orderDetails.GroupBy(orderDetail => orderDetail.CustomerId)
                         .Where(group => group.Count() == numberOrders)
                         .Select(group => group.Key)
                         .ToList();
```